# Re-raise multiple times with differing amounts?

Tags: rules, raise

I need this question answered. No limit Texas holdem. 
4 players $1/$2 blinds,
Pre-flop, 
Player 1 button, 
Player 2 small, 
Ect.

Player 4 raises to $4 (minimum raise, blind + $2), player 1 then re-raises to $12 ($4 + $8). If player 2 wants to re-raise again what is the minimum he must put in??? Is it $24 (double the $12), $20 ($12 plus the previous $8 re-raise), $16 or $14?? Please help as I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere.

Comment: Is this a Limit or a No-Limit game ?

Comment: Rather it is spread limit or no limit the minimum raise would always be the same, with the caveat that the minimum raise could not exceed the maximum bet in a limit game. This question would never come up for a fixed limit game since there is only one bet size, and the raise is the same as that bet size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of the last raise is the minimum size for the next raise. In the case you explained, player two at minimum must make it 20. That is the last raise was 8 dollars making it twelve to go, so the next minimum raise is eight more, making it 20 to go.

Comment: Yes, this is the standard rule. There are casinos that have different house rules.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Would you care to elaborate on what the other rules are and what casinos they are at. I think what I described is the rule and nobody varies from it. Of course with all in exception but that is really not in the scope of the OP's question.

Comment: At least three California cardrooms I know of have the rule that you must double to the total bet. Supposedly this prevents whipsawing, but that's not a real problem in no-limit IMHO. Also, casinos may treat blinds specially: the normal rule is that the big blind--and only the big blind--is treated as the opening bet, and the next raise must raise that amount. Some casinos treat smaller blinds as opening bets, thus allowing a smaller raise. Same issue with straddles. Also, some games may have blinds smaller than the actual limits: for example, a $2 blind with $5 minimum bet.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker That's helpful, have not played in CA for some time.